# Detecting Japanese characters in Java strings

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to detect if a java string contains Japanese characters. Since it does not matter to me if the characters form a grammatically correct sentence I thought I'd use a regex to match any Japanese character in the string like so:

```
package de.cg.javatest;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class JavaTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String aString = "なにげない日々。";
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[\\p{InHiragana}]");
        Matcher m = pat.matcher(aString);
        System.out.println(m.matches()); // false
    }
}
```

However, the print statement always shows `false`. I have tried altering the pattern to

```
[\\p{IsHiragana}]
[\\p{InHiragana}]+
```

and I have also entered the code points manually. Is there something I am missing, or do I have to take another approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Matcher.matches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()) returns true only when the pattern matches the whole string. [As Anonymous commented, not all character are Hiragana characters.](http://ideone.com/zyGIUm)

By changing the pattern as following, you can check if there's any Hiragana.

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(".*\\p{InHiragana}.*");
```

By using [`Matcher.find`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()), you don't need to modify the pattern.

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\p{InHiragana}");  // [..] is not needed.
Matcher m = pat.matcher(aString);
System.out.println(m.find()); // true
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. Maybe I should have paid more attention to the description of `Pattern.matches`. `Matcher.find` is exactly what I wanted.